# I have a code $scope.object1=$scope.object2 , change in object2 is making change in object1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

$scope.Object1=$scope.Object2
(assigning to reference and not to value). was this there in angular from beginning or is it a new feature ?

Comment: If you want to clone an object instead, this question may be of use to you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has absolutely nothing to do with angular. That's how javascript object inheritance works. Objects are always assigned by reference

Easy to see this for yourself

```
var a = {foo: 1};
var b = a;
b.foo = 2;
alert(a.foo);// 2
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the object1 is pointing to the memory reference of the object2, this is not an angular feature, in fact is a behavior of how the variable assignment works in javascript.

Angular includes a helper function to make copies to avoid this case, for example using angular.copy() you can make a copy of the object instead of pointing to the reference.

```
$scope.object1 = angular.copy($scope.object2);
```

In that way when the $scope.object2 changes, the changes are not reflected on the $scope.object1 because is not pointing to the object2 reference, object1 is a object copy of the object2 before change so is pointing to a new object reference.

So in javascript:

- Objects are references
- Primitives (numbers, strings etc) are passed by value.

Also you can take a look at:

[How does variable assignment work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509579/how-does-variable-assignment-work-in-javascript)

[Javascript equivalent of assign by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732589/javascript-equivalent-of-assign-by-reference)