# scope variable updated automatically when I am updating another scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting ajax request data and assigning to one scope variable 
`$scope.customerEvents = data;`
then I am using another variable to modify the data

```
    var datanew=data;
    datanew.unshift({'customer_events_id':   'ID','date':'Date','event':'Event','eventsubtype':'Event Subtype','eventtype':'Event Type','time':'Time','user_id':'User ID','user_mrn':'User MRN','user_name':'User Name','user_role':'User Role'});
    $scope.downloadcsv=datanew;
```

But customerEvents is getting updated.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 3):

you should use:

```
$scope.customerEvents = angular.copy(data);
```

Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.

That's the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy).

Also you can look at this question: [Javascript equivalent of assign by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732589/javascript-equivalent-of-assign-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, customerEvents and datanew are probably both referencing the same object (referenced by 'data'). Clone the array when you copy it to datanew and you'll be modifying *only* datanew and eventually $scope.downloadcsv and *not* customerEvents.

change `var datanew=data;` to `var datanew=data.slice()`;

Answer (score 0):

you have to do a deep copy of your object unless it will be referenced by the first variable.
you  can use:

- angular.copy(data)
- angular.merge(dst, src) : [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge).
- or you can use  jquery.clone()

Also you can refer to this post : [Deep copying objects in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360401/deep-copying-objects-in-angular)