# Const Variable Modified in Cross Reference

Tags: javascript, constants

The code below declares an `input_data` as a `const` variable that is never modified in the lifetime of the execution. I expect every `console.log` to output the same thing 3 times but that is not the case.

This code is modified to be minimal and easily understandable and reflects the functions and promises am using in the real code. Could you tell me how and why this is happening and also show a working code with the same structure that doesn't modify that `const` variable

```js
const platform = "test";
const input_data = {
  "test": true
};

function verify(data) {
  let cmd = input_data;
  cmd.valid = true;
  return cmd;
}
console.log("#req", input_data);
let command = verify(input_data);
console.log("#req", input_data);

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  command.executed = true;
  resolve("successs")
}).then(result => {
  console.log("#req", input_data);
});
```

Below is the output I get

```
#req { test: true }
#req { test: true, valid: true }
#req { test: true, valid: true, executed: true }
```

---

**Instead it should be like this**

```
#req { test: true }
#req { test: true }
#req { test: true }
```

Comment: javascript does assignment by reference. And declaring an object as const does not prevent you from changing the values at its keys.

Comment: good point @TheFool, but am not changing the values on `input_data` 

Comment: yes you do. `let cmd = input_data` now command is your input object as it is a refence to the original. When you then do `cmd.valid = true` you added another key / value pair to the original object but you didnt violate the const.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732589/javascript-equivalent-of-assign-by-reference

Comment: `cmd` is a different variable here which is being modified, the real victim is `input_data` who is never modified

Comment: because cmd is referencing input_data. I told you now three times. Please go learn about assignment by refrence.

Comment: if you want to prevent it, by the way, create a fresh brand new object. With es6 you could do `let cmd = {...input_data, valid: true}`

Comment: easy @TheFool, thanks for your help, I hadnt come across this before.

Comment: @DisneyProgram, Use `let cmd = Object.assign({}, input_data);` this will shallow copy properties

Comment: yep, I just found it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value but i would never find that question if it were not for you guys because of the phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing [assignment by reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-javascript-references-work/#:%7E:text=On%20variable%20assignment%2C%20the%20scalar,at%20other%20variables%2C%20or%20references.).

When you do `let cmd = input_data`  you reference the 'input_data' object. Meaning any change to `cmd` will reflect in `input_data`.

You can prevent this by creating a new object.

#### es5

```
let cmd = Object.assign({}, input_data, {valid: true})
```

#### es6

```js
let cmd = {...input_data, valid: true}
```

So the final code would be

```
const platform = "test";
const input_data = {"test": true};

function verify(data){
    let command = Object.assign({}, data);
    command.valid = true;
    return command;
}
console.log("#req", input_data);
let command = verify(input_data);
console.log("#req", input_data);

new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    command.executed = true;
    resolve("successs")
}).then( result => {console.log("#req", input_data);});
```

Comment: This has been a great answer you fool 