# Javascript: reference an array with a variable, instead of duplicating it

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, reference

let's say I have two javascript arrays, like this:

```
arrA = [1,2,3]
arrB = [4,5,6]
```

Is there a way I can reference them with different variable names down then road?  If I do this:

```
arrC = arrA
arrD = arrB
```

it makes *copies* of the initial arrays, instead of making a pointer/reference to them.  So, if I mess with the value of `arrC`, `arrA` isn't updated.  Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample of code showing your scenario, since `arrC = arrA` does just make a new reference to the same array.

Comment: I used below code in firebug: 'arrA = [1, 2, 3]; arrC = arrA; arrC[2] = 9; console.log(arrA)'. It shows that arrA is updated.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I was re-assigning my variable name elsewhere in my code.  Thanks for the help - I'll accept an answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't make a copy. If you change `arrC`, it will change `arrA` too.

Try this :

```
var arrA = [1,2,3];
var arrC = arrA;
arrC.push(26);
console.log(arrA);
```

You'll see `[1, 2, 3, 26]` in the console.

The contrary is true : if you *want* to make a copy, you have to do it explicitly, for example with

```
var arrC = arrA.slice();
```

Comment: and if you **did** want to make a copy, use `var copy = arr.splice();`

Comment: what do you mean? it's the same thing you just edited your answer to include :)

Comment: I had edited before, but I was mostly referring to the fact that splice (with a p) doesn't return a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this post and Create an array within an object, this is a simple way.

[javascript variable reference/alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686990/javascript-variable-reference-alias)

Comment: 1) Don't just link to another question, do it in comment so that somebody can mark it as duplicate. 2) I don't see how it's related. 3) try to gain some rep so that you can comment instead of writing answers that aren't answers. 4) welcome on SO :)