# Use a for loop to modify and store iterations of same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to modify an array then store that modification in another array than do another modification and store that to the second array etc, but my second array is just d instances of the last iteration of my for loop. This seems like a closure problem but I can't figure out a workaround?

```
for (var d=1; d<arr1.length; d++) {
       remove = arr1.splice(d,1).toString(); 
        arr1.splice(d+1,0,remove);
     arr2.push(arr1);
   }
    return arr2;
```

Comment: please add the arrays as well.

Comment: And the expected output.

Comment: I'm starting out with [1,2,3,4] as arr1 and I'm hoping to have arr2 end up as [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2]]. I think I need to change d<arr1.length to d<arr1.length-1 but that still doesn't solve my problem - I keep getting 4 sets of [1,3,4,2] as my result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all modified versions of your array, I suggest using an array of arrays, in this case let's call that top-level array `master`. Each time you modify your array, you would just push it to the `master` array.

This would give you what is called a "2d array". Then you would be able to access any version of your array that you wanted to. Your first array would be `master[0]`, second would be `master[1]`, etc. To access the first element of your second array, you can then just say `master[1][0]`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was trying to do that by pushing arr1 to arr2 each time?

Comment: I know your problem now. Arrays are reference objects. Read up on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686990/javascript-variable-reference-alias

Comment: And this @keli http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm